# Searching specific lines of files using GREP

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, grep, command-line-interface

I have a directory with many text files. I want to search a given string in specific lines in the files(like searching for 'abc' in only 2nd and 3rd line of each file). Then When I find A match I want to print line 1 of the matching file.

My Approach - I'm doing a grep search with -n option and storing the output in a different file and then searching that file for the line number. Then I'm trying to get the file name and then print out it's first line.

Using the approach I mentioned above I'm not able to get the file name of the right file and even if I get that this approach is very lengthy.

Is there a better and fast solution to this?

Eg.
1.txt

```
file 1
one
two
```

2.txt

```
file 2
two
three
```

I want to search for "two" in line 2 of each file using `grep` and then print the first line of the file with match. In this example that would be 2.txt and the output should be "file 2"

**I know it is easier using `sed`/`awk` but is there any way to do this using `grep`**?

Comment: `awk` would be better suited here.. also, adding an example with expected output along with the commands you tried will get you an answer.. no need full file content, just 2-5 lines for 2-3 input files along with exact output you want

Comment: grep doesn't have any way to specify which line number to search and no way to print specific line from before the match.. so, why do you want to do this with grep... you also mention you need a fast solution, which grep isn't going to give you

Comment: I guess I've found a method for doing this using grep and cut

Comment: You can to it using assembly code too but that'd also be a bad approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sed` instead (GNU sed):

*parse.sed*

```
1h                 # Save the first line to hold space
2,3 {              # On lines 2 and 3
  /my pattern/ {   # Match `my pattern`
    x              # If there is a match bring back the first line
    p              # and print it
    :a; n; ba      # Loop to the end of the file
  }
}
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -snf parse.sed file1 file2 ...
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
sed -sn '1h; 2,3 { /my pattern/ { x; p; :a; n; ba; } }' file1 file2 ...
```

You might want to emit the filename as well, e.g. with your example data:

*parse2.sed*

```
1h                 # Save the first line to hold space
2,3 {              # On lines 2 and 3
  /two/ {   # Match `my pattern`
    F              # Output the filename of the file currently being processed
    x              # If there is a match bring back the first line
    p              # and print it
    :a; n; ba      # Loop to the end of the file
  }
}
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -snf parse2.sed file1 file2 | paste -d: - -
```

Output:

```
file1:file 1
file2:file 2
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$ awk 'FNR==2{if(/one/) print line; nextfile} FNR==1{line=$0}' 1.txt 2.txt
file 1

$ awk 'FNR==2{if(/two/) print line; nextfile} FNR==1{line=$0}' 1.txt 2.txt
file 2
```

- `FNR` will have line number for the current file being read

  - use `FNR>=2 && FNR<=3` if you need a range of lines
- `FNR==1{line=$0}` will save the contents of first line for future use
- `nextfile` should be supported by most implementations, but the solution will still work (slower though) if you need to remove it

Comment: Yes, `nextfile` is gawk-only, unless it's been picked up by mawk or some other awk version lately, but in any case it's not POSIX but it will work in gawk. The code should really be `FNR==2 { if (/two/) print line; nextfile }` though so `nextfile` gets hit whether `two` matched or not.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks, great point about the logic, edited the answer... just checked [gawk nextfile documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Nextfile-Statement) and it says: `For many years, nextfile was a common extension. In September 2012, it was accepted for inclusion into the POSIX standard. See the Austin Group website.`

Comment: it's still not in the spec yet though, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html, but it does look like several awks support it (though not all with identical semantics) and gawk even allows it with the `--posix` flag set.

Answer (score 4):

With `grep` and `bash`:

```
# Grep for a pattern and print filename and line number
grep -Hn one file[12] |        

# Loop over matches where f=filename, n=match-line-number and s=matched-line
while IFS=: read f n s; do 

  # If match was on line 2 or line 3
  # print the first line of the file
  (( n == 2 || n == 3 )) &&  head -n1 $f
done
```

Output:

```
file 1
```

Comment: can you explain what this is doing?

Answer (score 2):

**Only using `grep`, `cut` and `|` (pipe):**

```
grep -rnw pattern dir | grep ":line_num:" | cut -d':' -f 1
```

**Explanation**

```
grep -rnw pattern dir
```

It return name of the file(s) where the pattern was found along with the line number.
It's output will be somthing like this

```
path/to/file/file1(.txt):8:some pattern 1
path/to/file/file2(.txt):4:some pattern 2
path/to/file/file3(.txt):2:some pattern 3
```

Now I'm using another `grep` to get the file with the right line number (for e.g. file that contains the pattern in line 2)

```
grep -rnw pattern dir | grep ":2:"
```

It's output will be

```
path/to/file/file3(.txt):2:line
```

Now I'm using cut to get the filename

```
grep -rnw pattern dir | grep ":2:" | cut -d':' -f 1
```

It will output the file name like this

```
path/to/file/file3(.txt)
```

P.S. - If you want to remove the "path/to/file/" from the filename you can use `rev` then `cut` and again `rev`, you can try this yourself or see the code below.

> `grep -rnw pattern dir | grep ":2:" | cut -d':' -f 1 | rev | cut -d'/' -f 1 | rev`